# CSS and Jquery: addClass not overwriting css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass

I have a script that adds a class to an element on hover.

Issue is the new, added class does not seem to 'overwrite' the existing css (even though on my style sheet the added class is listed below the existing css).

I cannot use removeClass on the element as there is no actual initial class styling the element.

The 'initial' styling that needs to be overwritten is:

```
#menu ul li ul li {
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

The class that needs to be added is:

```
.whitebg {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

My script is:

```
$('#menu ul li ul li').hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass('whitebg');
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass('whitebg');
  }
);
```

Does anyone know a way I can fix this up?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) when there are multiple rules  targeting the same object with different selectors.

Comment: Also about CSS specificity, a nice little tool for comparing the weight of two selectors when in doubt is http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Why use the jQuery `.hover()` method at all?  Use the CSS pseudo-selector `:hover` instead. My 3-level menu (menubar with menus that have sub-menus) requires exactly zero lines of javascript. Your CSS can have `#menu ul li ul li` and `#menu ul li ul li:hover` with different colors. Because of the way we change colors during navigation, we also have `#menu ul li:hover ul li` and `#menu ul li ul:hover li` rules.  We later *enhanced* the menu with javascript *timers* so the menus would not snap closed the moment the mouse drifts outside the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the specificity. you can use `!important` as the other posts suggested but 
using `!important` in your  CSS is a **bad practice.**

```
Use that as you last option.
```

Instead use two classes..

Make sure the inner most li has the `default` class to it..

```
$('#menu ul li ul li').addClass('default').hover(
   function() {
      $(this).addClass('whitebg').removeClass('default');
   },
   function () {
      $(this).removeClass('whitebg').addClass('default');
   }
);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ytca7/2/)**

Comment: Thanks - I do agree with this but unfortunetly for me the CMS I am using makes it difficult to apply a class directly to that particular element. I could use JQuery to apply the class as in your example but that would require total reliance on JavaScript. That being said, in your opinion, which do you think is stronger: total reliance on JQuery or reliance on !important?

Comment: If you want the things be done really quick and dirty then !`important` is the way to go. Otherwise I would rely on javascript .. you would just need a extra `addClass` in the same selector.. i have updated the post and the fiddle for your reference

Answer (score 4):

`id` selectors take precedence over `class` selectors. You need `!important`

```
.whitebg {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: It is more accurate to say "In a selector, an `id` has higher specificity than a `class`" -- the truth is that more specific selectors take precedence over less specific selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the !important tag to the background-color in .whitebg class. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

then, you need code this:

```
#menu ul li ul li {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#menu ul li ul li.whitebg {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Only in this way, can we have a common parent class.

`!important` will be a compatibility problem.